# Saving to AWS DynamoDB from localhost

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-dynamodb

I have a web app developed locally. So far I have stored data to a downloaded version of DynamoDB but now I would like to start using the DB online instead.

Is it possible to save data online from localhost?

I have set the endpoint from:

http://localhost:8000

to:

https://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

But when I do this my localhost doesn't load.

I'm using node.js and express.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to save the data to DynamoDB online from local.

Use the below code to load the access keys and region info:-

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
```

**config json:-**

Please use your keys and DynamoDB table region.

```
{ "accessKeyId": "key", "secretAccessKey": "accesskry", "region": "us-east-1" }
```

**Remove this code if you have:-**

```
AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});
```

**Edit:-**

Yes, `config.json` is the file that you need to put in ROOT.

Also, when you use the AWS DynamoDB, you don't need to provide the endpoint. The endpoint will be derived by the region automatically.

Comment: There is good news, Thanks! However I can not remember how to update the config.js. Is it just a file I put in the root? So I did and I also added "endpoint": "https://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" to the config but it still doesn't work.

Comment: We can discuss in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134587/room-for-notionquest-and-arpo

Comment: Yay! It works, the problem was in the fact that a table online was empty so I had to move some stuff from the local DB to the online version. Thanks once again:)